# Difference in speeds between iperf and broadband speed test

Tags: networking, bandwidth, broadband

Why would these iperf commands give such slower results to an in browser broadband speed test?
I've tried a few different free iperf servers and they all give similar results. I am wondering if I am perhaps misunderstanding how these network speeds work.

iperf3.exe -c iperf.astra.in.ua -R

[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth       Retr

[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  34.0 MBytes  28.5 Mbits/sec   28             sender

[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  34.0 MBytes  28.5 Mbits/sec                  receiver

---

iperf3.exe -c iperf.astra.in.ua -R

[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth

[  4]   0.00-10.01  sec  23.0 MBytes  19.3 Mbits/sec                  sender

[  4]   0.00-10.01  sec  22.9 MBytes  19.2 Mbits/sec                  receiver

---

---

Internet speed test using google.com in browser.

156.1 Mbps download

20.2 Mbps upload

Latency: 9 ms
Server: London

Comment: Where are _you_ physically? And what speed test site are you using in browser? I don't recall google.com providing that service directly.

Comment: I'm in the UK. If you google "speed test" it comes up as the top result for doing a speed test using google.

Comment: If I google "speed test" the top results are either Ookla's speedtest.com or Netflix's fast.com (then AT&T, then Telstra, then Xfinity...) – nothing from Google itself. Though I did find a speed test site provided by Google Fiber, but it only tests against servers in the USA and its result page isn't anything like what you posted here.

Comment: A few more things: What kind of physical connection do you have (both LAN and WAN)? Is your LAN connection Wi-Fi or Ethernet? Is the WAN connection fiber or ADSL or 4G? Have you tried using iperf's "multi-stream" mode using the `-P` option? (Sometimes this makes a difference with link aggregation.) Have you tested other devices against this server? (For Android, the HE.NET app has iperf3 built in.) Have you tested between two computers on your LAN (one as server and one as client)?

Comment: https://ibb.co/zJKwfQD that's that the speed test looks like

Comment: Interesting – that looks like a new feature they've only made available in some locations. What do you get if you visit Ookla's https://www.speedtest.net/ and choose some server in Ukraine? (For example, "Lviv - ASTRA ISP" is actually the same provider that you were using for iperf – it would be interesting to see if there are any differences between an iperf test and a browser test. However, also test against other servers in various locations as well.)

Comment: Speedtest.net Liviv - ASTRA ISP
 DOWNLOAD Mbps 57.84
 UPLOAD Mbps 20.88
Slower but not as slow as the iperf tests